# 'data type mismatch in criteria expression' in Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a query in Access2013 which was working well. Then I added a criteria expression "`AND item_name = '553046514'`". It looks like below. Later I decided to remove that added criteria, but then I got the error. I tried to change that criteria in many ways but most of which brought the same error:

```
AND item_name Not Like '000*'
AND item_name <> '0'
AND item_name like '000*'
AND item_name not in ('0')
AND item_name not in ('a', 'b')
AND item_name like '5*'
```

But those work:
`AND item_name like '0*'` (return nothing. But no error)
`AND item_name like '4*'` (return nothing. But no error)

It even worked when I deleted the criteria but changed DataValue function to Format() function. But same error will come when query on top of this query.

I don't know what is wrong and why that has problem with data type.

The query:

```
SELECT i.item_name AS ITEM, s.site_name AS DC, sum(r_quantity) AS R_DAY, sum(p_quantity) AS P_DAY, DateValue(r_ship_date) AS RQST_SP_DATE, DateValue(p_ship_date) AS PRMS_SP_DATE
FROM s, sos, i
WHERE sos.site_id = s.site_id
AND sos.item_id = i.item_id
AND item_name = '553046514'
AND s.site_name not like 'Agg-*'
AND sos.state = 'Open'
GROUP BY i.item_name, site_name, DateValue(r_ship_date), DateValue(p_ship_date)
ORDER BY i.item_name, site_name, DateValue(r_ship_date), DateValue(p_ship_date);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the problem. With certain item (553046512), the r_ship_date is NULL which cannot be dealt by DateValue or CDate. So under that situation a data type mismatch error will accur.

My trial with different criteria act differently because they may or may not include item 553046512.

Answer (score 0):

I know NOT IN is typically associated with the expectation of a Sub-query.  You might want to change from

```
AND item_name Not Like '000*'
AND item_name <> '0'
AND item_name like '000*'
AND item_name not in ('0')
AND item_name not in ('a', 'b')
AND item_name like '5*'
```

to

```
AND NOT item_name Like '000*'
AND item_name <> '0'
AND item_name like '000*'
AND NOT item_name in ('0')
AND NOT item_name in ('a', 'b')
AND item_name like '5*'
```

Comment: Thank you DRapp for your reply. I am sorry I should have not formated the query like that. I meant those are different replacements for "AND item_name = '553046514'" that I added.